# How to see c++ and c# dll dependencies?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a python project that calls a c++ wrapper dll that calls a c# com interop dll.
In my computer, with all frameworks and programs installed, my project runs very well.

But in a computer that just got formatted it doesn't.
I allready installed c++ 2008 redistribute and the c++ part is working but when I call a function from it (that will call the c# correspondent one), it gives an error.

I want to know what are the dll dependencies from both c++ and c# dll's to see what is missing :)

Comment: Look into a Thinstaller from VMWare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you need [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Dependency Walker (a.k.a. `depends.exe`) works for both native DLLs and managed DLLs.

It is included in some Visual Studio versions, and can also be downloaded [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).